# How to list the top level folders of a drive using VBScript?

Tags: wmi, vbscript, directory

I'm looking for VBScript code that will list the top level folders of the D: drive and not the subfolders. 
I use the following WMI query so far but it gives me all folders and goes down to many levels. Also seems to just stop for a reason I have not determined just yet.

```
Set colFolders = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Directory Where Drive = 'D:'")
```

**EDIT:**

After more searching I found something that gives me what I wanted. Just in case there are others looking here is the VBScript for folders and size:

```
Set objFSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("D:\")
for Each folder in objFolder.SubFolders
    On Error Resume Next
    size = folder.size
    if Err.Number <> 0 Then
        size = -1
    end if
    wscript.echo folder.name,size
Next
```

Comment: You should post an answer and mark it closed.

Answer (score 1):

To specify that you want only the top-level folders, you need to add the `Path = '\\'` condition to the `WHERE` clause:

```
strComputer = "."
Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")

Set colFolders = oWMI.ExecQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Directory WHERE Drive = 'D:' AND Path = '\\' ",, 48)

For Each oFolder In colFolders
    WScript.Echo oFolder.Name
Next
```

Alternatively, you can use an `ASSOCIATORS OF` query to get the top-level folders as subfolders of the drive root:

```
strComputer = "."
Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colFolders = oWMI.ExecQuery _
    ("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_Directory.Name='D:\'} " _
        & "WHERE AssocClass = Win32_Subdirectory " _
            & "ResultRole = PartComponent",, 48)

For Each oFolder In colFolders
    WScript.Echo oFolder.Name
Next
```

But the `FileSystemObject` solution is probably easier.